# Static Variable Reset Android

Tags: android, static, static-methods, android-lifecycle

I'm using a **static method** and some **static member variables** related to that in a class, I have read that there is a chance that these static variables *may reset* at some point of time. My question is that is it assured that the app will starts from Application's `onCreate()` if something like this happens.

Thanks.

Comment: It is considered bad practice to hold important data in static fields. If you need to ensure your data is not being lost you need to use SaveInstanceState, PrefereneManager or database / files depending on your use case.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know static variables only resets at the time when application restarts otherwise they remains same all over the app

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart your application to reinitialise static variables

```
   Intent mStartActivity = new Intent(context, StartActivity.class);
    int mPendingIntentId = 123456;
    PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, mPendingIntentId,    mStartActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100, mPendingIntent);
    System.exit(0);
```